# Font loading on home page of site but not on others and also on different browsers

Tags: fonts, webfonts

I have a web font from Myfonts.com which I'm trying to install at   https://www.petrabishai.co.uk

I've followed the instructions from Myfonts.com which is to upload the fonts to the root folder of the site and then add this to the header document:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyFontsWebfontsKit.css">`

I've also edited the CSS file to include this:

```css
body {
    font-family:  Futura-Boo, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it appears on the home page of the site on various browsers but doesn't appear on the other pages. I assumed that as the reference to  it was in the header that that would then be automatically applied across every page. However I get a 404 error saying can't find the resource - see screenshot from the console in Safari.[1]

Any thoughts on how to fix this very appreciated. Many thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSodG.png

Answer (score 0):

Your MyFontsWebfontsKit.css file is at `https://www.petrabishai.co.uk/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css`

But it looks like other pages are trying to load the .css file from other relative paths. E.g.,

```
GET https://www.petrabishai.co.uk/workshops/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css
```

See the [Webfonts Troubleshooting](https://www.myfonts.com/help/#webfonts-troubleshooting)  tips on MyFonts.com:

> Some common causes of a 404 error are:
>
> - The location of the stylesheet that contains the @font-face rule does not match the relative path that is in your HTML  element.
>   ...

Comment: Many thanks for this. I started off updating the header document to <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../MyFontsWebfontsKit.css"> I also updated the font-face in the CSS document to font-face { font-family: 'Futura-Boo'; src: url('webFonts/Futura-Boo/font.woff2') format('woff2'), url('webFonts/Futura-Boo/font.woff') format('woff'); }

This resolved the problem on most pages but the Collections section was still trying to load the css from other relative paths. I then updated the header document with the full path to the css and this has solved it. Really appreciate your help.